# Tutorial does not compile

Tags: c++, wtl

The following code [from Michael Dunns series on WTL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4518/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-VII-Splitter-Windows) does not compile

```
template <bool t_bVertical = true>
class CMySplitterWindowT : public CSplitterWindowImpl<CMySplitterWindowT<t_bVertical>, t_bVertical>
```

First line of errors is: 
'WTL::CSplitterWindowImpl' : 't_bVertical' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'TBase'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTL changed between 8 and 9

The base constructor needs to be called to set the member variable

```
template <bool t_bVertical = true>
class CMySplitterWindowT : public CSplitterWindowImpl<CMySplitterWindowT<t_bVertical> >
{
public:
    DECLARE_WND_CLASS_EX(_T("My_SplitterWindow"), CS_DBLCLKS, COLOR_WINDOW)

    CMySplitterWindowT() : m_bPatternBar(false), CSplitterWindowImpl<CMySplitterWindowT<t_bVertical> >(t_bVertical)
    { }
```

from the readme -

"Splitter Window:

•Changed orientation from template argument to data member to reduce memory use"